# Get variable definition as string using Clang

Tags: clang, libclang

What way would you recommend of getting the definition of (global) variable `var` as it is in the source code snippet `int var = MACRO(5) + 5;` using Clang/Libclang if I have `var`'s definition cursor?

One way would be to use the cursor's extents to extract the definition from the source code, but are there other ways, like reconstructing the definition using the AST?